# Session Variables and List Object not Updating Correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I should be able to figure this out, but I've been fighting with it for quite a while now.

I have a popup page that has several available requests that a user can select from. Based upon the page that the user is accessing, there could be one request or multiple requests available for that user.  The single and multiple request are both saved on different session variables.

I need to know the single request that the user selected at the beginning of the process. It works fine except when the user is allowed to add multiple requests, the single request session variable is also updated.

For example, single request variable has "Florida"; then, the user reaches the multiple request page and adds GA and LA to the multiple request session variable. The single request variable is also updated to include GA and LA even though the flag is false and  never reached that line.  I don't want it to be updated. I need that single request to be available at all the time, so the user can see it if and when requested.

Here is a sample code where the issue is happening:

```
List<Request> temp = new List<Request>();
List<Request> mySearchRequest = new List<Request>();
List<Request> listSingleRequest = new List<Request>();
if (SessionWrapper.currentRequest.AvailableRequests != null)
{
    mySearchRequest = (List<Request>)SessionWrapper.currentRequest.AvailableRequests;
}

if (SessionWrapper.currentRequest.MultipleRequests != null)
{
    temp = (List<Request>)SessionWrapper.currentRequest.MultipleRequests;
    var test = temp.Find(delegate(Request req) { return req.RequestId == id && req.Desc == description; });
    // Checking if we have on the container already
    if (mySearchRequest.Any(r => r.RequestId == id && r.Desc == description) == false)
    {
        mySearchRequest.Add(test);
        if (SessionWrapper.currentRequest.SingleRequest == true && mySearchRequest.Count() == 1)
        {
            listSingleRequest.Add(test);
            SessionWrapper.currentRequest.singleRequest = listSingleRequest ;
            listSingleRequest = null;
        }
    }
}
//Set multiple request session here
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
JF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it almost all night, I was able to fix it. I am not sure if that is the most efficient way of doing it, but it works for now.

```
if (SessionWrapper.currentRequest.MultipleRequests != null)
{
    temp = (List<Request>)SessionWrapper.currentRequest.MultipleRequests;
    var test = temp.Find(delegate(Request req) { return req.RequestId == id && req.Desc == description; });
    // Checking if we have on the container already
    if (mySearchRequest.Any(r => r.RequestId == id && r.Desc == description) == false)
    {
        mySearchRequest.Add(test);
        if (SessionWrapper.currentRequest.SingleRequestPage == true && mySearchRequest.Count() == 1)
        {
            foreach (var item in test)
            {
               //Create a new request object and add it to the list
                Request request =  new Request();
                request.RequestId == item.RequestId;
                request.Description == item.Description;
                listSingleRequest.Add(request);
            }
            SessionWrapper.currentRequest.singleRequest = listSingleRequest ;
            listSingleRequest = null;
        }
    }
}


 if (SessionWrapper.currentRequest.singleRequest != null)
   {
      tempRequest = SessionWrapper.currentRequest.singleRequest.ToList();
      foreach (var test in tempRequest)
      {
       Request request =  new Request();
       request.RequestId == item.RequestId;
       request.Description == item.Description;
       listSingleRequest.Add(request);
     }
    SessionWrapper.currentRequest.ViewRequest = listSingleRequest;
    listSingleRequest = null;
 }
```